# DROP [columns] FROM tags;

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

There are 103 questions tagged with [columns](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/columns), and they are all over the map: several Excel questions that involve a column of data somehow (i.e., Excel questions), some questions about manipulating columns in text editors, and others about word processing programs like Word.

In each case, the tag for the program being used is sufficient for getting the right people to see the question. I propose that we do away with it completely, and nothing will be lost.

Comment: +1. I feel like we did this at least once already though. Can't find anything though.

Comment: A [meta-tag:tag-cleanup-request] with an *already witty* title? Oh me oh my, what am I going to do?! (Edit: Except upvote it..........)

Comment: Our Excel experts seem to generally have comprehensive knowledge, and text editors don't have many functions.  For those two, [columns] isn't needed to attract the right people for answers.  Word users tend to have more specialized experience, and issues dealing with page layout or tables are somewhat "specialties" that could benefit from having a tag.  [columns] is a bit meta.  [table] has been deprecated.  For Word, rather than simply drop the [columns] tag, it might be better to replace it with a subject tag in some cases.  At least for some of these, [page-layout] might be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [columns](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/columns) tag has been cleaned up and out. 0 questions remain.

Comment: @Sathya Can you please change the status of this tag-cleanup to completed? Thank you.